# Getting 'AttributeError' when attempting to scrape webpages

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm currently working on a silly project to test my Python skills. I want to be able to scrape data for a lottery game and analyze it to measure a pattern.

The goals:

- Scrape numbers history. Including dates.
- Store the data in a text or CSV
- Analyze the data, and have the computer make an educated guess.

I first attempted to scrape the data by downloading the HTML files directly and storing it within the program to scrape.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


# Establishes soup and html data
with open('lotto_test.html', 'r') as html_file:
    content = html_file.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')

# defines where the data will be written
file = open('Numbers.txt', 'w')

# finds data in class, prints and writes to file
for ul in soup.find_all('ul', class_='resultsNums'):
    numbers = ul.text
    print(numbers)
    file.write(numbers)

# same as ul, except for the date
for dates in soup.find_all('div', class_='resultsDrawDate'):
    dod = dates.text
    print(dod)
    file.write(dod)

file.flush()
file.close
```

Though the data is formatted a bit strangely, this successfully accomplished what I'm looking for. However, I would like to gather as much data as possible.

I am trying to approach this differently, by having the computer scrape the data straight from the webpage. Then going page by page, and storing data from a years worth of drawings. And have written the script this way:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = HTMLSession()
url = 'https://www.lotterypost.com/game/98/results'

def get_data(url):
    r = s.get(url)
    r.html.render(sleep=1)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.html.html, 'html.parser')
    return soup
    
def next_page(soup):
    page = soup.find('div', {"class":"CSR-Paging"})
    if not page.find('span', {"class":"CSR-PrevNext"}):
        url = "https://www.lotterypost.com/game/98/results" + str(page.find('div', {'class':'CSR-Paging'}).find('a')['href'])
        return url
    else:
        return

while True:
    soup = get_data(url)
    url = next_page(soup)
    if not url:
        break
    print(url)
```

When run, the output is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Volumes/Local NAS/Cross Platform Files/Lotto Calc/scraper.py", line 23, in <module>
    url = next_page(soup)
  File "/Volumes/Local NAS/Cross Platform Files/Lotto Calc/scraper.py", line 15, in next_page
    if not page.find('span', {"class":"CSR-PrevNext"}):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

I'm not sure what to do from here. I thought `.find()` was a built in function of Python. Does this mean it is not finding the attribute I specified? Or is it confused about what attribute I am looking for exactly? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your `page` variable is `None`. Therefore, you can't operate on it. You should add a pre-check to that conditional block to fail-early if this is the case.

I have separated out these conditional blocks in an attempt to make this more clear. Also, I have over-commented this for clarity.

```
def next_page(soup):
    # Retrieve the `CSR-Paging` element.
    page = soup.find("div", {"class": "CSR-Paging"})

    # We couldn't find a `CSR-Paging` element, so return `None`.
    if not page:
        return

    # We found a `CSR-PrevNext` element, so return `None`.
    if page.find("span", {"class": "CSR-PrevNext"}):
        return

    # Retrieve the `CSR-Paging` element's nearest anchor.
    path = str(page.find("div", {"class": "CSR-Paging"}).find("a")["href"])

    # Return the path appended to the page constant.
    return "https://www.lotterypost.com/game/98/results" + path
```